# UIPickerView changed on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, ios11

On our app, we have a UIPickerView that lets you choose a season. However, on iOS 11, the **Done** button and **Cancel** button disappear and are only visible while switching between apps. Has anyone else experienced this?

Screenshots of iOS 11 behavior, with iOS 10 behavior below.

Edit: Here's a [complete sample app](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=88468216267374189145) with the issue:

Here's the code for setting up the picker view

```
func setUpPickerView(){

    self.seasonPicker = UIPickerView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.frame.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3))
    self.seasonPicker.delegate = self
    self.seasonPicker.dataSource = self

    self.seasonTextField.inputView = self.seasonPicker

    let toolbar = UIToolbar.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: 50))
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default

    let labelTitle = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 50, width: 150, height: 20))
    labelTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.black
    labelTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    labelTitle.text = "Select a Season"
    labelTitle.sizeToFit()

    let typeFeild = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: labelTitle)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(didClickPickerCancel))
    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(didClickPickerDone))
    toolbar.items = [cancelButton, flexSpace, typeFeild, flexSpace, doneButton]

    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    self.seasonTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

}
```

[image: UIPickerView with missing done button]
[image: UIPickerView's done button reappears while switching between views]
[image: UIPickerView working as expected on iOS 10]

Comment: Those buttons aren't part of the picker view and I doubt it has anything to do with them. More likely, it has to do with the way you are presenting or laying out the container you are displaying all of that in. You should post the code that creates that view/controller.

Answer (score 10):

Turns out there's a simple fix for this:

```
self.seasonPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Internally, looks like they've changed the behavior of input accessory views to have this property on by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had allocated using `initWithFrame` hence I changed like

```
   UIPickerView picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 320, 480)];
```

to

```
UIPickerView picker =  [UIPickerView new];
```

and also for `UIToolbar`

`UIToolbar toolbar = [UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];`

to

```
UIToolbar toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
```

and now Done is visible... issue was old iOS 10 were allowing with fix sizes... now new is best way to use for iOS 11